# Single value discriminated unions?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Is it possible in F# to have a discriminated union whose value is assigned only once? I'm imagining something like:

```
type DogAttributes = { Age: int; Color: string; }

type Dog =
| Rex of DogAttributes ({ Age = 5; Color = "Brown"; }
| Fido of DogAttributes ({ Age = 3; Color = "White"; }
```

The Rex value would always have the assigned DogAttributes and couldn't be changed.

Comment: No, that's not possible. I'm not sure how one would want to use it, either.

Comment: It would be useful if I knew, at compile time, all of the values of the specific Dog I wanted to use. Obviously I could keep this data elsewhere and look it up though, which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: `Rex` and `Fido` don't feel like *types*, they feel like *values*. It seems like a better way to model your problem domain is `let rex = DogAttributes { Age = 5; Color = "Brown" }`.

Comment: Having them be values is how I'm currently writing my code, but there are a few places where I have code that has to match against the dog's name like `match dog.Name with | "Rex" ....` This made me question my approach and whether I should make each Dog a type itself.

Comment: Also, this seems like a reasonable approach if I wanted to keep them types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059587/in-f-how-can-i-attach-metadata-to-discriminated-union-values?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @rmunn it seems like you're confusing types with values. `Rex` and `Fido` should be instances of the same entity.

```
type Dog = { Name: string; Age: int; Color: string }
```

*Discriminated Unions* aren't in place here either, they can be considered *Enums* with benefits.

```
type Breed =
| JackRussell
| Labrador
| Poodle
```

You could of course combine them...

```
type BadDog =
| JackRussell of Dog
| Labrador of Dog
| Poodle of Dog

let badJack = JackRussell({ Name = "Rex" ; Age = 5 ; Color = "brown" })

let badName = 
    match badJack with 
    | JackRussell(dog)
    | Labrador(dog)
    | Poodle(dog) 
        -> dog.Name
```

...but in the given context you'd be doing more matching then desirable.

```
type GoodDog = { Name: string; Age: int; Color: string; Breed: Breed }  
let goodJack = { Name = "Rex" ; Age = 5 ; Color = "brown" ; Breed = Breed.JackRussell }  // (*)
```

(*) Without the `BadDog` type definition you could've used `JackRussell` instead of `Breed.JackRussell` (resolving ambiguity).

In the comments you mentioned wanting to match against the dog's name in a more direct way. Consider this [active pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns):

```
let (|DogName|) = function dog -> dog.Name

match goodJack with
| DogName "Rex" 
    -> printfn "Hello Rex"
| _ -> printfn "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would accomplish what you want:

```
type DogAttribute = { Age : int; Color : string }

type Dog =
| Rex of DogAttribute
| Fido of DogAttribute

[<AbstractClass>]
type DogBase(dog, age, color) =
    member x.Age = age
    member x.Color = color
    member x.Dog = dog { Age = x.Age; Color = x.Color}      

type Rex() = 
    inherit DogBase(Dog.Rex, 5, "Brown")        

type Fido() = 
    inherit DogBase(Dog.Fido, 3, "White")
```

But, at that point, it seems like you'd be better off just using OO-style polymorphism. *Discriminated unions aren't the only way to express a sum type*<sup>†</sup>, just the nicest. But, abstract classes can serve just as well.

<sup>†</sup>Proof: The code described in this answer.